# Why is python's pip install behaving strangely in a script but fine in python prompt?

Tags: pip, python-import

I'm trying to install a module from withing a python script using pip. Here is the contents of `script.py`:

```
#/usr/bin/python2.7
# I'm the file called `script.py`

import sys, importlib, pip
print(sys.version); print(sys.path) # For debugging
try:
    importlib.import_module('docopt')
except ImportError:
    pip.main(['install', '-U', 'docopt'])
finally:
    globals()[pack] = importlib.import_module('docopt')
```

Runnting this script, e.g. using `python2.7 script.py` gives me:

```
$ python2.7 script.py
2.7.9 (default, Oct  3 2016, 17:42:24) 
[GCC 4.3.2 20081105 (Red Hat 4.3.2-7)]
['/usr/lib/python27.zip', '/usr/lib/python2.7', '/usr/lib/python2.7/plat-linux2', '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-tk', '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-old', '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload', '/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages']
No module named docopt
Downloading/unpacking docopt
  Cannot fetch index base URL https://pypi.python.org/simple/
  Could not find any downloads that satisfy the requirement docopt
Cleaning up...
No distributions at all found for docopt
Storing debug log for failure in /root/.pip/pip.log
Traceback (most recent call last):
  [...]
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/importlib/__init__.py", line 37, in import_module
    __import__(name)
ImportError: No module named docopt
```

So problems with **internet connection/ssl** or something transport related. However, t**he same commands work perfectly fine in the python interactive** interpreter, when I enter them by hand (copy&paste them):

```
$ python2.7
Python 2.7.9 (default, Oct  3 2016, 17:42:24) 
[GCC 4.3.2 20081105 (Red Hat 4.3.2-7)] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import pip, sys
>>> print(sys.path)
['/usr/lib/python27.zip', '/usr/lib/python2.7', '/usr/lib/python2.7/plat-linux2', '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-tk', '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-old', '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload', '/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages']
>>> pip.main(['install', '-U', 'docopt'])
Downloading/unpacking docopt
  Downloading docopt-0.6.2.tar.gz
  Running setup.py (path:/tmp/pip_build_root/docopt/setup.py) egg_info for package docopt

Installing collected packages: docopt
  Running setup.py install for docopt

Successfully installed docopt
Cleaning up...
0
```

Again, the thing that weirds me out is, that **it works interactively** i.e. running `python2.7` in the shell and then entering the very same code by hand. However, not when **I run the script file** with `python2.7 script.py`. So In one case, on the same machine, the same interpreter has internet access in the other case it does not.

I'm running out of troubleshooting ideas. I used the same machine and user to get above results. There is no python-startup file, so that is not making the commands magically work interactively. The contents of `sys.path` are the same in both cases. I'm not behind a proxy.  Any ideas what could be missing in the script?

Answer (score 0):

> Cannot fetch index base URL https://pypi.python.org/simple/

indicates that for some reason your python interpreter cannot access to internet. There can be plenty of reasons for that. Do you use a HTTP proxy ?

Comment: Nope, not using a proxy. The thing that weird's me out is, that it works from the interpreter i.e. running `python2.7`in the shell and then entering the very same code by hand. However, not when I do `python2.7 script.py`. So In one case, on the same machine, the same interpreter has internet access in the other case it does not.

Comment: totally blind guess: do you have SELinux enabled ?

Comment: Never heard of it, so I guess not. `$ sestatus
bash: sestatus: command not found`

Comment: so probably enabled then on a modern redhat. try the shell command `/usr/sbin/sestatus` as root to get the status. If it is enabled, disable it with `setenforce 0` then try again.

Comment: Okay, I'm sure that SELinux is not enabled.

Comment: Ok, then try something else to reach the internet from python interpreter (for example, `requests`) and see if that works.

Comment: Request seems to be fine. Some indication, that it might have to do with ssl-certificates